# How does this program work

Tags: c++

This is my first C++ program. It prints the number of words in the input.

My first question, how does it go into the loop and add to the count? is it every time i type the space character? if so, how does it know I'm trying to count words?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count;
    string s;
    count = 0;
    while (cin >> s)
        count++;
    cout << count << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

My second question. Can someone explain to me what namespace std means for a begineer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cin will capture input until a space, yes. The specific style of loop you have will go until an End-Of-File (EOF) is found or until bad input is provided. That loop doesn't look like common C++ practice to me, but it's described [here](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/io-operators.html).

2.`namespace std` is how you tell the compiler where to look to find the objects you're referencing in your code. Because different objects are "inside" different namespaces, you either have to tell the compiler where they are specifically (aka std::cin) or tell it for convenience where an object you use will be in the future (with `using namespace std`).

Comment: I find it actually two common ways.  One is as he shows, and the other  fails miserably if it encounters EOF or any other error early.

Answer (score 7):

When you do cin >> string. You will read a word and put it in the string. Yes, it will read char by char until reach the delimiter.

Std means Standard. Standard C++ library is inside the std namespace. You can rewrite or code without the *using namespace std*:

```
int main() {
    int count;
    std::string s;
    count = 0;
    while (std::cin >> s)
        count++;
    std::cout << count << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I discourage that novices use the *using namespace std* statement because it is harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: That, and `set` is an unfortunately commonly used name.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `cin >> s` attempts to read a `std::string` from input stream. If the attempt succeeds, then the returned value of `cin >> s` implicitly converts into `true` and the while loop continues, incrementing the counter. Otherwise, the while loop exits when the attempt fails, as there is no more data to read from the input stream.

You can use `std::distance` to count the words, as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
        std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(std::cin), end;
        size_t count = std::distance(begin, end);
        std::cout << count << std::endl;        
        return 0;
}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Hldz3

In this code, you create two iterators `begin` and `end`, passing both to `std::distance` function. The function calculates the distance between `begin` and `end`. The distance is nothing but the number of strings in the input stream, because the iterator `begin` iterates over strings coming from the input stream, and `end` defines the end of the iterator where `begin` stops iterating. The reason why `begin` iterates over strings is because the template argument to `std::istream_iterator` is `std::string`:

```
 std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(std::cin), end;
                     //^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you change this to `char`, then `begin` will iterator over `char`, which means the following program will count the number of characters in the input stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
        std::istream_iterator<char> begin(std::cin), end;
        size_t count = std::distance(begin, end);
        std::cout << count << std::endl;        
        return 0;
}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/NH52y

Similarly, you can do many cool things if you start using iterators from `<iterator>` header and generic functions from `<algorithm>` header.

For example, let say we want to count the number of lines in the input stream. So what change would we make to the above program to get the job done? The way we change `std::string` to `char` when we wanted to count characters, immediately suggests that now we need to change it to `line` so that we could iterate over `line` (instead of `char`).

As no `line` class exist in the Standard library, we've to define one ourselves, **but the interesting thing is that we can keep it empty** as shown below, with full working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

struct line {};   //Interesting part!

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream & in, line &) 
{ 
   std::string s; 
   return std::getline(in, s);
}

int main() {
        std::istream_iterator<line> begin(std::cin), end;
        size_t count = std::distance(begin, end);
        std::cout << count << std::endl;        
        return 0;
}
```

Yes, along with `line`, you've to define `operator>>` for `line` as well. It is used by `std::istream_terator<line>` class.

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/iKPA6